# AuthenticationContextIntegratedAuthExtensions.AcquireTokenAsync now failing on 4.0-preview with unknown_user

Tags: adal

I've got some code that uses ADAL v3, which uses the extension method in the title to get a token for the current Windows user. I tried the new [v4 package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory/4.0.0-preview), and now the call fails with "unknown_user: Could not identify logged in user".

Is this a known problem? Or do I need to do something different when using v4?

Here's the basic code I'm using:

```
$authAuthority = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/common"
$vstsResourceId = "XYZfake"
$vsClientId = "ABCfake"

$authContext = New-Object Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.AuthenticationContext -ArgumentList $authAuthority
$userCredential = New-Object Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.UserCredential

$task = [Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.AuthenticationContextIntegratedAuthExtensions]::AcquireTokenAsync($authContext, $vstsResourceId, $vsClientId, $userCredential)
$task.GetAwaiter().GetResult()
$authResult = $task.Result
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for the failure is that I used the netstandard1.3 binary, and the `PlatformInformation.GetUserPrincipalNameAsync()` method is a [dummy](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-dotnet/blob/a033eb5b8766ea06a05c6bd07776fc2d66464767/adal/src/Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory/Platforms/netstandard1.3/PlatformInformation.cs#L41)--it just returns an empty string.

```
    public override async Task<string> GetUserPrincipalNameAsync()
    {
        return await Task.Factory.StartNew(() => string.Empty).ConfigureAwait(false);
    }
```